# openldap give group write access to subtree

Tags: ldap, openldap, access-control-list

I have

```
dn: ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: people
```

and group of admins for it:

```
dn: cn=people-admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
cn: admins of people group
uniqueMember: uid=admin1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
```

and I add such rules to allow `people-admins` add/delete/modify users in `people` groups

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
delete: olcAccess
-
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: to dn.one="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" by group.exact=cn=people-admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com write by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: to dn.base="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" by group.exact=cn=people-admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com write by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: to dn.children="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" by group.exact=cn=people-admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com write by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: to dn.subtree="ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" by group.exact=cn=people-admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com write by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write by * none
```

then I try to add new user to `people` group using credentials of admin1, and got this:

```
ldapadd -x -H ldap://127.0.0.1:3000/  -D "uid=admin1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com" -W
dn: uid=test1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: test1
sn: test
givenName: test1
cn: test test1
displayName: Test1
userPassword: test1
adding new entry "uid=test1,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
        additional info: no write access to parent
```

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/729647/openldap-ldap-user-cant-add-entry-insufficient-access-no-write-access-to-pa) similar question, but it receive wrong answer, because of `dn.entry` does not exists in openldap.

Comment: If you're just starting out, I recommend switching to using `groupOfNames` rather than `groupOfUniqueNames`. Most systems that interact with OpenLDAP expect groupOfNames by default, including OpenLDAP itself. This will save you from having to adjust the defaults.

Comment: @84104 But `dn.entry` not mentioned here http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html plus if replace for example `dn.base` with `dn.entry` `slapd` give `<olcAccess> handler exited with 1`, why you belive that `dn.entry` exists?

Comment: @84104 But I need constraint that `member` of group is `unique`, how can I achieve this with `groupOfNames`?

Comment: Briefly mistook the behavior of `attr=entry` for `dn.entry=`. Comment notifications may not reflex edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `group.exact` not work with `groupOfUniqueNames`.
I solved it by changing this rule:

```
by group.exact=cn=people-admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com write
```

to this rule:

```
by group/groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember=cn=people-admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com write
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just starting out, I recommend switching to using `groupOfNames` rather than `groupOfUniqueNames`.

Most systems that interact with OpenLDAP for group membership expect groupOfNames by default, including OpenLDAP itself. While they can generally be modified to use groupOfUniqueNames/uniqueMember (e.g. [`sssd-ldap`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd-ldap) `ldap_group_member` or your own use in OpenLDAP's olcAccess), this will save you from having to adjust the defaults.

---

There are differences between [`distinguishedNameMatch`](https://www.irt.org/rfc/rfc4517.htm#sect_4.2.15.), used by `member` and [`uniqueMemberMatch`](https://www.irt.org/rfc/rfc4517.htm#sect_4.2.31.) used by `uniqueMember`, but the former is usually sufficient.

```
$ ldapadd <<EOF
dn: cn=testgroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
> objectclass: groupofnames
> member: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
> member: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
> EOF
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: self@EXAMPLE.COM
SASL SSF: 56
SASL data security layer installed.
adding new entry "cn=testgroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_add: Type or value exists (20)
    additional info: member: value #0 provided more than once



$ ldapsearch cn=testgroup
dn: cn=testgroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: testgroup
gidNumber: 12345
member: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com

$ ldapmodify <<EOF
dn: cn=testgroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com
add: member
member: uid=testuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
EOF

SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: self@EXAMPLE.COM
SASL SSF: 56
SASL data security layer installed.
modifying entry "cn=testgroup,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"
ldap_modify: Type or value exists (20)
    additional info: modify/add: member: value #0 already exists
```